# Travis CI to allow multiple failues for various python version

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have the following `.travis.yml` which I would expect to allow failures on python 2.6, 2.7 and nightly. 
For some reason it only recognises the nightly as allowed to fail, and the build fails due to 2.6 failing.

I'm guessing it might be the default and that it doesn't recognise my `allow_failures` section at all. 
`travis-lint` produces no errors.

Any ideas as to what goes wrong?

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "nightly"
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - python: 2.6
    - python: 2.7
    - python: nightly
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - "python setup.py develop"
# command to run tests
script: py.test -v mandelbrot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `allow_failures` element under the `matrix` elements only applies to what is defined inside the `matrix` - makes sense now that I see it.

Fix:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - python: "2.6"
    - python: "2.7"
    - python: "3.2"
    - python: "3.3"
    - python: "3.4"
    - python: "nightly"
  allow_failures:
    - python: "2.6"
    - python: "3.2"
    - python: "nightly"
```

Comment: In fact, that is because you used non-string values https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5113#issuecomment-156829617